# How to serialize a one to many relation in django-rest using Model serializer?

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework, one-to-many, django-serializer

These are my models and serializers. I want a representation of Question Model along with a list of people the question was asked to.

I am trying this:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PATCH'])
def questions_by_id(request,user,pk):
    question = Question.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = QuestionSerializer(question)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

But I get an empty dictionary (`{}`). However when I remove the `asked` field from `QuestionSerializer` I get a complete representation of `Question` along with `Places` serialized nicely. What am I missing ?

```
class AskedToSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AskedTo
        fields = ('to_user', 'answered')

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        places = PlaceSerializer(many=True, required=False)
        asked = AskedToSerializer(source='askedto_set', many=True)
        fields = ('id', 'created_on', 'title', 'places', 'answered','asked')
        extra_kwargs = {'created_by': {'read_only': True}}

class Question(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    places = models.ManyToManyField(Place, blank=True)
    answered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class AskedTo(BaseModel):
    ques = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    replied = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Place(models.Model):
    g_place_id = models.CharField(max_length=20,primary_key=True)
    json = models.TextField(null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I figured it out. There were two errors.

Changed this:

```
class AskedToSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AskedTo
        fields = ('to_user', 'answered')
```

to this (notice the change in fields, fields on model and serializer didn't match)

```
class AskedToSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AskedTo
        fields = ('to_user', 'replied')
```

Secondly, I needed to define any extra fields outside `class Meta`

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    places = PlaceSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    asked = AskedToSerializer(source='askedto_set', many=True)    

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'created_on', 'title', 'places', 'answered','asked')
        extra_kwargs = {'created_by': {'read_only': True}}
```

Notice the change in definition of `places` and `asked`.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I have this **models.py**:

```
class Section(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
     description = models.TextField(blank=True)
     user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="sections", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Feed(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
     link_rss = models.URLField(max_length=500)
     link_web = models.URLField(max_length=500)
     description = models.TextField(blank=True)
     language = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
     logo = models.URLField(blank=True)

     sections = models.ManyToManyField(Section, related_name="feeds")
```

And I completed the **serializers.py** this:

```
class FeedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     sections = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

     class Meta:
         model = Feed
         fields = '__all__'


class SectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     feeds = FeedSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

     class Meta:
         model = Section
         exclude = ('user',)
```